# How to convert dict to expressions in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am facing problem in implementing some logic using python

For example

```
{"a":"b", "c":1}
```

When I print "a" I need to get "b" and when I print "c" I need to get 1

Something like below

```
>>> a
'b'
>>> c
1
```

how to resolve this problem

Comment: You have a dictionary and you can simply get the values with indexing `>>> d['a']
'b'`

Comment: Why do you even want to do such thing? Look like you have [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
>>> input_dict = {"a":"b", "c":1}
>>> for key, value in input_dict.items():
...     try:
...             exec( "{} = {}".format(key, value))
...     except:
...             exec( "{} = {}".format(key, "'" + str(value) + "'"))
... 

>>> a
'b'
>>> c
1
```

- More complex test case

  ```
  >>> input_dict = {"a":"b", "c":1 , "d" : {1,2,3}}
  >>> for key, value in input_dict.items():
  ...     try:
  ...             exec( "{} = {}".format(key, value))
  ...     except:
  ...             exec( "{} = {}".format(key, "'" + str(value) + "'"))
  ... 
  >>> d
  set([1, 2, 3])
  >>> a
  'b'
  >>> c
  1
  ```

Comment: what if other than string and int, like datetime object

Comment: @RajeshKumar It will try if it can assign the value to key without any `NameError`'s . If it cannot it changes into string.

Comment: @RajeshKumar I have added another test case. Hope that is what you asked

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should not do such things, because you will pollute module namespace.

```
In [1]: a
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

In [2]: c
NameError: name 'c' is not defined

In [3]: d={"a":"b", "c":1}   
In [4]: globals().update((k, v) for k, v in d.items() )

In [5]: a
Out[5]: 'b'

In [6]: c
Out[6]: 1
```